# Number of ways to distribute 10 things among 6 people given that the number of things given to two people doesn't exceed 4?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Here is a more specific question:

> Find the number of ways of giving $10$ identical gift boxes to 6
>   people : $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$, $F$ in such a way that total number
>   of boxes given to $A$ and $B$ together does not exceed $4$.

I am currently learning about problems which are related to *Combinations with Repetitions*, for the most part of it I am able to solve the basic questions, but this one stumped me.

Can you suggest how to approach this problem?

Comment: Brute force?  Give no boxes to A, B and distribute 10 among C-F, then 1 box among A, B and 9 among C-F, then ... then 4 boxes to A, B and 6 to C-F.

Comment: Do it in two steps. Assign 0-4  gift boxes to A, B. Find how many ways you can do this. Assign remaining 10-6 gift boxes to C-F. The first and second steps are called composition problems. Look it up on wikipedia. Multiply values in two steps and sum over all cases.

Comment: Use inclusion/exclusion.  First solve the problem without the constraints on A and B.  Then subtract the cases where A's gifts exceed 4, and subtract the cases where B's gifts exceed 4.  Finally, add the cases where both A's and B's gifts exceed 4.  Alternatively, the problem is easy to solve with a generating function, if you have studied GFs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x_A$, $x_B$, $x_C$, $x_D$, $x_E$, and $x_F$ represent the number of gift boxes given to persons $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$, and $F$, respectively.  Since a total of ten boxes are distributed to these six people, 
$$x_A + x_B + x_C + x_D + x_E + x_F = 10 \tag{1}$$
Since $A$ and $B$ together receive at most four of these gifts, we must solve equation 1 in the nonnegative integers subject to the restriction that $x_A + x_B \leq 4$.

This can be solved by casework.  If 
$$x_A + x_B = k \tag{2}$$
then for equation 1 to be satisfied, we must have 
$$x_C + x_D + x_E + x_F = 10 - k \tag{3}$$
for $0 \leq k \leq 4$.

A particular solution of the equation 
$$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n = m \tag{4}$$ 
in the nonnegative integers corresponds to the placement of $n - 1$ addition signs in a row of $m$ ones.  For instance, if $m = 10$ and $n = 5$, 
$$1 + + 1 1 1 + 1 1 + 1 1 1 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 1$, $x_2 = 0$, $x_3 = 3$, $x_4 = 2$, $x_5 = 4$. Consequently, the number of solutions of equation 4 in the nonnegative integers is 
$$\binom{m + n - 1}{n - 1}$$
since we must choose which $n - 1$ of the $m + n - 1$ positions required for $m$ ones and $n - 1$ addition signs will be filled with addition signs.

Thus, equation 2 has 
$$\binom{k + 2 - 1}{2 - 1} = \binom{k + 1}{1} = k + 1$$
solutions and equation 3 has 
$$\binom{10 - k + 4 - 1}{4 - 1} = \binom{13 - k}{3}$$
solutions in the nonnegative integers.  Thus, when $x_A + x_B = k$ and $x_C + x_D + x_E + x_F = 10 - k$, the number of solutions of equation 1 is 
$$(k + 1)\binom{13 - k}{3}$$

Since $0 \leq k \leq 4$, the number of ways of distributing ten gifts to persons $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$, and $F$ so that $A$ and $B$ together receive at most $4$ of those gifts is 
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{4} (k + 1)\binom{13 - k}{3} = \binom{13}{3} + 2\binom{12}{3} + 3\binom{11}{3} + 4\binom{10}{3} + 5\binom{9}{3}$$

Answer (score 2):

Assume for the moment that we have an unlimited supply of boxes to be distributed to $6$ individuals, whereby the first two together may obtain no more than $4$ boxes. In a generating functions approach the combined allocations to A and B then are counted as
$$1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+5x^4={1-6x^5+5x^6\over(1-x)^2}\ ,$$
and the allocations to the remaining four people as
$$(1+x+x^2+x^3+\ldots)^4={1\over(1-x)^4}\ .$$
The generating function for the full problem then becomes
$$\eqalign{F(x)&={1-6x^5+5x^6\over(1-x)^6}=(1-6x^5+5x^6)\sum_{k\geq 0}{-6\choose k}(-x)^k\cr &=(1-6x^5+5x^6)\sum_{k\geq0}{5+k\choose k}x^k\ .\cr}$$
We now have to extract the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in this expansion:
$$N={15\choose10}-6{10\choose5}+5{9\choose4}=2121\ .$$

Comment: You seem to have misread the question.  $A$ and $B$ *together* receive at most four gifts.  You interpreted the question to mean that $A$ receives at most four gifts and $B$ receives at most four gifts.

Comment: @N.F. Taussig: I don't think so. A and B together receive $r\in[0..4]$ boxes.These boxes can be split in $r+1$ ways among A and B. In all this leads to the term $1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+5x^4$. Nevertheless: There was a numerical error in the final sum, which I have now corrected. My result now is the same as yours.

Comment: Alternatively one may consider a weighted GF for A and B, like $1+tx+(tx)^2+ (tx)^3+ (tx)^4$ each. By completing to all six people, the coefficient of $x^{10}$ is  $286+440t+495t^2 + 480t^3  + 420t^4 + ...$ and the sum of first five terms is $2121$.

Answer (score 2):

The problem may be rephrased by asking each people to have at least one gift. The new number of gifts would be 16 and the A+B condition, 6.

Let's place the 16 gifts in a row. There are 15 spaces between them in which we have to place 5 delimiters. In general, g gifts may be distributed to p people in $\binom {g-1}  {p-1}$ ways.

The A+B condition means that the second delimiter has to be in the 2-nd, 3-rd, 4-th, 5-th or the 6-th space. The rest of four delimiters may be placed as follows :

$\binom{1}{1}\binom{13}{3} + \binom{2}{1}\binom{12}{3} + \binom{3}{1}\binom{11}{3} + \binom{4}{1} \binom{10}{3} +\binom{5}{1}\binom{9}{3} = 2121$

Answer (score 2):

Of the $10$ boxes, suppose $r$ boxes are given to $A$ and $b$ together. Then $0\leq r \leq 4$. The number of ways of giving $r$ boxes to $A$ and $B$ is $$ {2+r-1\choose r} = {r+1\choose r} = r+1.$$

The number of ways in which the remaining $(10-r)$ boxes can be given to $C, D, E, F$ is $$ {4+(10-r)-1\choose 10-r} = {13-r \choose 10-r} = {13-r \choose 3}$$

Consequently, the number of ways in which $r$ boxes can be given o $A$ and $B$ and $(10-r)$ boxes to $C, D, E, F$ is, by product rule, $$(r+1) \times {13-r \choose 3}$$

Since $0 \leq r \leq 4$, the total number of ways in which the boxes may be given is, by the sum rule, $${\sum_{r=0}^{4} (r+1) \times {13-r \choose 3} }$$

Answer (score 0):

Redefine the questions as $U = \{\text{gift in A or B}\}$ and $V$ the complement. Going over to probability we can see that $N=\{\text{fraction}\, U=n\} \in Bin(1/3,10)$ and we are taskt to evaluate

$$
P(N <= 4) = q^10 + 10*p*q^9 + \frac{10*9}{2}p^2q^8 + \frac{10*9*8}{2*3}p^3q^7 + \frac{10*9*8*7}{2*3*4}p^4q^6,
$$ with $p=1/3,q=2/3$. Now multiply by $6^{10}$ and you get the number of combinations.