# Generating function problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

Using generating functions, find the number of ways to divide $n$ coins into $5$ boxes that meet the condition that the number of coins in boxes $1$ and $2$ is an even number that does not exceed $10$, the remaining boxes contain $3$ to $5$ coins.

I have found that the generating function of this problem is $(1+x^2+x^4+x^6+x^8+x^{10})^2(x^3+x^4+x^5)^3$. I have tried to convert it into $\frac{(x^{12}-1)^2x^9(x^3-1)^3}{(x^2-1)^2(x-1)^3}$ however I can't improve any further more.

Comment: That correct. What makes you think that it could be "improved further"? $\quad$ If you're looking to calculate the coefficient of $x^n$, then expand the denominator using the negative binomial series / Maclaurin series, EG $1/(x-1) = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \ldots$. It will still give you a summation form for the coefficient, and not an immediate exact answer.

Comment: here is an example of reducing a multinomial coefficient to an algebraic sum of binomials
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2820559/number-of-ways-to-distribute-10-things-among-6-people-given-that-the-number-of-t

Comment: One notable feature of this GF is that it satisfies $f(x)=f(x^{-1})x^{44}$. From this one can deduce that the number of ways to divide $44-n$ coins is the same as the number of ways to divide just $n$ of them. (To see this directly, let the number of coins in each box be $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5)$ for a total of $n$ coins. Then $(10-a_1,10-a_2,8-a_3,8-a_4,8-a_5)$ is a valid distribution of $44-n$ coins, so there's a bijection between these two counts.)

Answer (score 0):

All that is needed is to multiply out your product and read of the answer:

$x^{35} + 3 x^{34} + 6 x^{33} + 7 x^{32} + 8 x^{31} + 9 x^{30} + 15 x^{29} + 20 x^{28} + 27 x^{27} + 29 x^{26} + 36 x^{25} + 39 x^{24} + 47 x^{23} + 46 x^{22} + 49 x^{21} + 45 x^{20} + 49 x^{19} + 46 x^{18} + 47 x^{17} + 39 x^{16} + 35 x^{15} + 26 x^{14} + 21 x^{13} + 13 x^{12} + 8 x^{11} + 3 x^{10} + x^{9}$

That reads there is 1 possible way to put 35 coins in the boxes (20 in the 2 boxes and 3*5 in the 3 boxes. There is 1 possible way to put in 9 coins (zero in the 2 boxes and 3 times 3 in the 3 boxes). There are zero ways to put more then 35 or less then 9. No need to "simplify" it into a fraction where I think you did it wrong.